# AWS GLUE Workflow: How to add both success and fail state to the same job

Tags: aws-glue

I have a scenario where I need to run the workflow despite the state of the jobs in the workflow. There are 2 nodes. I created a on demand trigger which will trigger Job_1 and Job_2. Once Job_1 and Job_2 is success or fail I need to run job_3 in Node 2. No matter the state of Jobs in node 1 I need to run job in Node3.

I have created the code:
Condition_1:

```
glue_client.create_trigger(
        Name='condition_check_success',
        WorkflowName=workflow_name,
        Type="CONDITIONAL",
        Predicate={
            'Logical': 'ANY',
            'Conditions': [
                {
                    'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                    'JobName': 'Job_1',
                    'State': 'SUCCEEDED'
                },
                {
                    'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                    'JobName': 'Job_2',
                    'State': 'SUCCEEDED'
                },
            ],
        },
        Actions=[
            {
                "JobName": 'Job_3',
            }
        ]
    )
```

Condition_2:

```
glue_client.create_trigger(
        Name='condition_check_failed',
        WorkflowName=workflow_name,
        Type="CONDITIONAL",
        Predicate={
            'Logical': 'ANY',
            'Conditions': [
                {
                    'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                    'JobName': 'Job_1',
                    'State': 'FAILED'
                },
                {
                    'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                    'JobName': 'Job_2',
                    'State': 'FAILED'
                },
            ],
        },
        Actions=[
            {
                "JobName": 'Job_3',
            }
        ]
    )
```

Workflow is created, but the Job_3 is not triggered.
Am I doing something wrong with the code?
I need to run Job_3 no matter what happens to Job_1 and 2. But it should run only at node 2.

Comment: While Glue workflow may (or may not) fit your requirements, I'd recommend using Step Functions or Airflow for data pipeline orchestration.

Comment: @Isc as you suggested GLUE Workflow is not that used friendly and straight forward.
I will go back to Step Function.